# PHP make checkers board from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get mysql to handle board data such as location and having the board display the black and red pieces in the board

the board having values such as

row 8 to 1
and
columns A to H

so i can then use mysql to move between the board

Question :
How do i convert that array into mysql so it can have the board row and column data then give values to the rows and columns so i can display the pieces and use those values to move the pieces in the board

```
    function displayboard(){




$Board = array
    (
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    );

        $row = 0;
        print "<form>";
        print "<table border = 1>";
        while ($row < 8){ // Counts to 8. (from 0...7 = 8 times. 0 ... 8 = 9 times)
           print "<tr>";
           $row++;
           $col = 0; // reset column to 0 each time printing one row.

           while ($col < 8){
            print "<td>";
            if($Board[$row][$col] == 0)
            {

                print "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"box[]\" value=\"$value\">";
                // Add \ before " otherwise it will treat as the end of the quote.

            }
            print "</td>";
            $col++;

           }

           print "</tr>";

        }
        print "</table>";
        print "</form>";

}
```

Comment: sorry How do i convert that array into mysql so it can have the board row and column data then give values to the rows and columns so i can display the pieces and use those values to move the pieces in the board

Answer (score 0):

This is not very efficient, but is a very easy way to achieve what you want.  That is, assuming you are asking how to store and retrieve a small array out of MySQL into PHP for the purpose of checkers.  If that is not what you are asking, please clarify your question.

Somewhere in MySQL, you have a table.  Let's call this table `boards`.  Whatever other columns you want to have in this table, no biggie, but leave one in there for string data.  Then use [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode your array.

```
$yourboarddata=json_encode($Board);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO boards (data) VALUES (\"" . mysql_real_escape_string($yourboarddata) . "\");");
```

When you are ready to retrieve it later, you can use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Note that this uses a decent amount of data.  You could save a lot of storage by making binary data out of your board, but this is a simple way for you to start.

Comment: when you mean binary data do you mean files

Comment: how do i convert that array into binary data

Comment: I was just thinking that on a simple level, you only need two bits per square.  You could hold 4 squares in a single byte.  Values for the two bits could be 0 for no piece, 1 for red piece, 2 for black piece, and 3 would be unused.  16 bytes for the whole board.  Actually, cut that in half since only half of the spots on the board can contain pieces.  So, your top initial row might be 01010101 in binary, which is equal to 55 in hex, 85 in dec.  Concatenate all of these bytes together and toss it in your DB.  Alternatively, you could store the positions of the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your board data in a database, but what happens if you want to generate boards of varying sizes? You'll need to bare that in mind. Something similar to the following may suffice if you can maintain it sufficiently:

```
Table: boards
    id        INT PRIMARY KEY
    board_id  INT
    x         TINYINT
    y         TINYINT
    checked   ENUM('0','1') DEFAULT '0'
```

That way, you could query your database for a single board and build it using it's `x` and `y` values, and whether it's checked or not.

Comment: Who plays checkers with boards of varying sizes?  That could be fun.